# Laravel - controller for post(different categories) - logic

Tags: laravel

I'm preparing IT blog with admin panel. Posts have categories like databases, operation systems etc. Every category has own site. How should I create a logic to display, route and manage(CRUD)?
I think it can be in one controller, which have parameter $category, which will be use to show specific posts. Something like this(between post-category is one-to-many-invert relation):

```
public function index()
{
     $posts=Post::where('category_id',$category)->get();
}
```

EDIT:

Categories:
programming, databases, other

Target URL:
blog/programming
blog/databases
blog/other

Above sites should have all posts from specific category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, if I've understood the question, that you're looking for a simple Category controller.

```
class CategoryController extends Controller {
  public function view($categorySlug)
  {
    $posts = Post::whereHas(['category' => function ($query) use($categorySlug) {
      $query->where('slug', '=', $categorySlug);
    }])->paginate(2);

    return view('my.view', compact('posts');
  }
}
```

The next question comes from the structure of the posts slug. For example, lets say that you have `my.blog/category-slug` that points to the above. Are your posts `my.blog/category-slug/post-slug` or are they `my.blog/post-slug` or `my.blog/year/month/day/post-slug`?

Comment: @3D_fun yes but I assume each post has its own individual page? What is the structure of that url?

Comment: Hi, sorry for delay, but Your tip was correct. I create CategoryController with specific function and it works. Thanks!